# Import Access table to oracle

Tags: oracle, ms-access

I have a problem importing a table to oracle. When I import it a field is import for example:
In access I have '20,200' and import to oracle '20' or ‘125.35’ in access and import to oracle as '12535'

In access it is declared as number, and in oracle it is already changed to text, float...

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- EDIT -----------

Is only a field that is giving problems. Yhe field in access is declared as number, and when I import the table to access it convert the field to binary_char

And import OK, but then I change that type to float or text, or other, and when I import info to that table, it import the fields like this examples:

In access: '20,200' -> to oracle '20'

In access: '125.35' -> to oracle '12535'

This is the code I used:

```
Option Compare Database

Function load_tables()

    Dim resposta

    varReturn = SysCmd(acSysCmdInitMeter, " ", 36)
    varReturn = SysCmd(acSysCmdSetStatus, " ")

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False

    varReturn = SysCmd(acSysCmdSetStatus, "Insert In Emb")
    DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO INFAR_Emb( Emb_ID, N_Registo, Descr, Compart, " & _
                                    "Data_Compart, Grupo_Hom_ID, Me_ID, " & _
                                    "Data_Alter, Data_Alt_Comp) " & _
                "SELECT [Emb_ID], [N_Reg], [Descr], [Compart], " & _
                                    "[Data_Compart], [Grupo_Hom_ID], " & _
                                    "[Me_ID], [Data_Alter], [Data_Alt_Comp] " & _
                                    "FROM [Emb] where [Emb_ID]=257"
```

Comment: I'm not clear on exactly what it is you are trying to do, and what you're seeing. Perhaps an example or two of the problem field definitions in Access and their counterpart in Oracle would help. Also, what it is you're seeing and what it is you want to see.

Comment: just added new info about the problem

Comment: We still need more... how are INFAR_Emb and Emb defined in their respective databases and which field(s) is it getting wrong.

Comment: Using DoCmd.RunSQL is a TERRIBLE idea, most importantly since you've turned off warnings, which means it will run the update and throw away all the errors. That means your data is corrupted, because you have no idea what got correctly processed and what didn't. Execute the SQL with CurrentDB.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError and if it's throwing errors, you'll find out what they are.

Comment: EMB is the access table, and INFAR_Emb is the oracle table. The access field is defined as number(double and with automatic decimal numbers)
The oracle field was already defined as : float precison 10, number 8,3, nvarchar 15

Comment: just run the currentDB.Execute, and with warning enable, and dont show any warnings and insert the values.

Comment: And `describe INFAR_Emb` gives you what result?

Comment: Running a DML statement with CurrentDB.Execute without dbFailOnError means you're doing EXACTLY what you'd be doing with SetWarnings Off and DoCmd.RunSQL -- you're again executing a command that when it has errors, will write inconsistent updates. In short, you're corrupting your data, because you have no idea what updates/inserts completed and what ones didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just find whats is wrong.. i have to create again the odbc to assume the new values of the table. the importation is working great now :).. tks all

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't think it is possible to have have field/column defined as `float precison 10, number 8,3, nvarchar 15` - unless that's all the options you've tried; however, I will hypothesise that it is really `FLOAT(8)`

If I'm wrong, try the following in SQL*Plus (or an equivalent Oracle client)

```
describe INFAR_Emb
```

And post the results for the field/column in question.

On to my hypothesis. The thing is with FLOAT, if you put a precision in, it is a [Binary Precision](http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-datatypes.html), not decimal. If you multiply by 0.30103, you will get the approximate number of decimal digits of precision it will hold. In the case of   `FLOAT(8)`, it's ~2

That would explain the problem with `125.35`, which rounds to `125`, but not `20200` (which I assume you added the comma to when you asked your question) - that leave some more to ponder.

It's probably sufficient to change the field/column to `NUMBER` (with no precision or scale) and be done with it.